# RxJava Loop for doing async work

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am using [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) library, i want compress the images using RxJava. Following is the example from the library documentation.

```
new Compressor(this)
        .compressToFileAsFlowable(actualImage)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<File>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(File file) {
                compressedImage = file;
            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                showError(throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

This works very well. Now i want to compress a list of images, how can i use this technique to get a list of compressed file paths?

I tried adding this method in a for loop but the returned list was empty because the accept method was not even called once and the code reached the return statement. Following is my method

```
   @NonNull
    private ArrayList<String> compressFiles(ArrayList<String> files, File directory) {
        final ArrayList<String> filesToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String filepath : files) {
            new Compressor(this)
                    .compressToFileAsFlowable(new File(filepath))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(File file) {
                            filesToReturn.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        }
        return filesToReturn;
    }
```

How can i change this method using RxJava so accept method only triggers when all the files have been compressed and list is filled?

I tried searching for RxJava loops/Flatmap but i couldn't figure them out. I am new to RxJava. Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In RxJava, you would use Observable.fromIterable():

```
Observable.fromIterable(files)
   .flatMapIterable(files -> files)
   .flatMap(filepath -> new Compressor(this).compressToFileAsFlowable(new File(filepath)))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(new Consumer<File>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(File file) {
            compressedImage = file;
        }
   }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            showError(throwable.getMessage());
        }
   });
```

Comment: I am unable to add that compressor method in the flatmap method.

Comment: that is because Compressor returns Flowable and flatMap expects Observable. You should use Flowable.fromIterable...

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more possible results:

1. Completable will be called when all images have been processed
2. Flowable will push results to subscriber as they are finished processing (honors backpressure)

Please look at subscribeOn. I use the computation scheduler, because cpu bound work should be executed on a bounded threadpool. IO is unbounded.

When you subscribe to Completeable or Flowable you have to apply observeOn with Android-MainUI-Scheduler.

Rember that subscribing to an Flowable/Observable should only be done, when state muste be changed. Otherwise compose observables together.

```
// Will call complete, when all files finish
private Completable compressFiles(ArrayList<String> files) {
        return Flowable.fromIterable(files)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(new Function<String, File>() {
                    @Override
                    public File apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        return Paths.get(s).toFile();
                    }
                })
                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<File, CompletableSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public CompletableSource apply(File file) throws Exception {
                        return new Compressor(appContext)
                                .compressToFileAsFlowable(file)
                                .singleOrError()
                                .toCompletable();
                    }
                });
    }


// Will push each file to subscriber as one finishes
private Flowable<File> compressFiles2(ArrayList<String> files) {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(files)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<String, File>() {
                @Override
                public File apply(String s) throws Exception {
                    return Paths.get(s).toFile();
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<File, Publisher<? extends File>>() {
                @Override
                public Publisher<? extends File> apply(File file) throws Exception {
                    return new Compressor(appContext)
                            .compressToFileAsFlowable(file)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Can you please write it without the lambda? And i didn't understand the . map method

Comment: The map-Operator just takes a 'x' and returns a 'y'. So it just transforms a value. In this case it gets a string and transforms this string to a File.

Comment: I use java 7, I don't use lambda. So i just have to write two methods? One for map to receive a string and return a file, and one for flatmapcompletable that takes a file and return the compressor file?

Comment: When i subscribe to either of these methods, i will be getting my compressor files in the onNext method?

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. I subscribed to the Completable but i only got the onDone method. how can the compressed file be retrieved?
And if subscribe to the Flowable, i get a method like accept and i am getting one file in it. Maybe i can use them to populate my list?

Comment: I updated compressFiles2. Completeable just tells you, that every item emitted from upstream has been processed. When all items has been processed, you get onComplete. Flowable will call onNext for each processed file. I suggest you subscribe with onError. Some operation may throw an exception. If an exception is thrown your subscriber gets unsubscribed. If you want to update your UI from this observable, you subscribe to the Flowable in the activity and change the state. To bridge from the reactive world just use toList() and then subscribe.

Comment: as you updated the compressFiles2 method, what should i subscribe on now? to get onNext and onCompleted both from compressFiles2?
I am using  compressFiles2(files).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(?? what should go here?)

Comment: compressFiles2(files).ob‌​serveOn(AndroidSched‌​ulers.mainThread()) is enough. In subscribe may handle onNext and onComplete. For more help please ask another specific question.